# Let an app have an independent mouse (like vm)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, mouse, sandbox

At work they use a really old app to fetch some data that hasn't autodownload. So every 10minutes i must manually go, switch to that app, and click a button to start the process.

¿Is there any way to let an app have it's own mouse/cursor?. So i can code the clicks with robotjs or something and do my tasks without interruptions?

I don't like the idea of having an entire windows virtualized, just to have that independent mouse.
I've also checked sandboxie, but it doesn't look to let the apps have a separate mouse.

Comment: It depends. Some UI automation techniques can work without co-opting the mouse; the possibilities vary based on your technical experience, and even the technology used to code the app. Have you tried something like AutoHotkey?

Comment: I need a mouse click on a nonfocused app. I don't think AutoHotkey can cover that :(

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I'm [pretty sure it can](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/74239-mouse-click-to-non-active-window/). If you are a programmer, you might also be able to use something like Microsoft's [UI Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview).

Comment: Interesting, i will check it!